# Getting App Access Token for facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm trying to generate app access token for facebook. I used the below request for generating the app access token.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret
```

But I'm getting below error.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803,
      "fbtrace_id": "GX983WVEz1Y"
   }
}
```

But when I copied The app is and app_secret in App Token Tool, It gave me the access token. But when I tried to generate it by sending the request, it throws above error.

Also, Do I need to add anything here:

```
key=value
```

Do I need to add client credential as a key?. Is it beacuse of this I'm getting this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Corrected my answer:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET

It worked for me.

Comment: This method is used for generating the access token for users. I want to generate app access token, which doesn't require the user to log in.

Comment: I have one more query. How are you using this token with graphRequest api. The token returned will be a string . But GraphRequest api requires a type of  AccessToken

Comment: @AmandaFernandez From that graphRequest api what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: I want to get the details of the post made by public pages and public groups. I'm trying to parse facebook embes

Comment: how to have access token with permissions as the access token provided by this url does not work and fb says : you don't have sufficient permissions to do so.